# Minimal Hitting Sets Problem

Tags: decision-problem, sets, scheduling, set-cover

Let $\mathcal{I} = \{I_0, \ldots, I_{m-1}\}$ a collection of subset of some universe $U$.

We want to find a partition $P$ of $\mathcal{I}$ of minimal cardinality such that the intersection of each set in $P$ is **not** empty.

Is this, or the corresponding decision problem, a well known problem? I found many similar problem, such as the hitting set problem and the set cover problem, but I did not find my problem.

Also, in the context I'm using it, sets $I_j$ are closed intervals $[a_j, b_j]$ of real numbers. I've also looked into scheduling problems, with no results. Is this a well known scheduling problem?

Comment: Can you illustrate with an example? It looks the partition problem in the question is the optimization version of the usual hitting set problem, which is NP-hard. However, the case with closed intervals, which should be well-known, can be done in $O(n\log n)$ time.

Comment: @JohnL. I don't have an example, it's a subproblem that emerged from the study of a learned index structure. I already have a linear algorithm for the case with closed intervals: sort the `I_j`s lexicographically, and then proceed in a greedy way, which I think founds a minimal partition.

Comment: @JohnL. If this case is well known, do you know some names that are used to refer to it, or some references in general?

Answer (score 1):

This is NP-hard and is closely related to the set cover problem.

Define $s_x = \{I_j \mid x \in I_j\}$ for each $x \in U$.  The set cover problem is to find a minimal cardinality set $X$ such that $\cup_{x \in X} s_x = U$.  Any solution to this set cover problem immediately yields a partition $P$ of the same cardinality; namely, we initially treat each $s_x$ (for each $x \in X$) as part of the partition, and if two parts $s_x,s_y$ have some $I_j$ in common, we remove $I_j$ from one of them, and repeat until this is a partition.  Conversely, any solution $P$ to your problem yields a solution to the set cover problem of the same cardinality; namely, pick one element $x$ from the intersection of each part of $P$ and add it to $X$.

This shows that there is a one-to-one correspondence between solutions to your problem and solutions to the associated set cover problem.